# View with aggregate functions

Tags: sql-server

I have an employee transit table consisting of these fields:

- id
- Name,
- surname
- date and time transit
- direction of transit (entry or exit)

I should create a view that for each day shows the hours worked by the employee. Would anyone be able to help me out?

The hours worked would correspond to the difference between exit and entry and potentially an employee could do 2 entries and 2 exits per day

Comment: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/2029983) What do you specifically need help with? What have you tried? Why isn't it working? Have you looked at the syntax on how to `CREATE` a `VIEW`? What about the documentation/turorial didn't you understand? Have you looked at the documentation on aggregation function in SQL Server? What about *those* didn't you understand?

Comment: How should you handle night workers, i.e.: someone that enters one night and exits the next morning?

Comment: Divide and conquer - a technique every developer in any language should know. Try writing a query to get that information for a specific day. Once that works, you have a model you can apply to the actual goal. Use of clock-in data is a common question so some simple searching will likely be useful. Lastly, know your data. People can enter and exit many times during a day and between days. Don't assume.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE EmployeeTransit (
    EmployeeId int      NOT NULL,
    Time       datetime NOT NULL,
    [In]       bit      NOT NULL, -- if it's not in then it's out.

    CONSTRAINT Employee_PK PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (EmployeeId)
)
/* 
Assumptions:
* Each day starts with an in.
* Each day ends with an out.
* Ins and outs alternate.
*/

;
WITH cteD AS (
    SELECT EmployeeId, Time, [In], CAST(Time AS date) AS d,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY EmployeeId,  CAST(Time AS date) ORDER BY Time) AS RowNumber -- Odds must me in, even must be out.
    FROM EmployeeTransit
)
SELECT EmployeeId, d, SUM(m) AS Minutes
FROM (
    SELECT i.EmployeeId, i.d, DATEDIFF(minute, i.Time, o.Time) AS m
    FROM cteD i
        INNER JOIN cteD o ON i.EmployeeId = o.EmployeeId AND i.d = o.d AND i.RowNumber + 1 = o.RowNumber
    WHERE i.RowNumber % 2 = 0 -- it's an in. Therefore o is an out.
) T
GROUP BY EmployeeId, d
```

Comment: Employee_PK PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (EmployeeId)  seems unlikely. There can be multiple entries for each EmployeeId, surely?

Comment: Typo, I meant `(EmployeeId, Time)`. You seem very keen to shoot this down?

Comment: Shooting down? lol. I'm pointing out a mistake.